# android overlay and touchevent

Tags: android

**i want to touch the screen and then cube will change the position
i don't know where is wrong with my code   **

```
public class GLCamTest extends Activity {
private CamLayer mPreview;
private GLLayer glView,myRender;
static int counter=0;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    GLSurfaceView glView = new GLSurfaceView(this);
    myRender = new GLLayer(this);
    glView.setRenderer(myRender);

    counter++;
    if (counter==2) {
        MediaPlayer mp=MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.track);
        mp.start();
    }
}



/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();



    this.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);

    final Window win = getWindow(); 
    win.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    // Hide the window title.
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);


    GLSurfaceView glView = new GLSurfaceView(this);
    myRender = new GLLayer(this);
    glView.setRenderer(myRender);




    glView=new GLLayer(this);

    mPreview = new CamLayer(this, (PreviewCallback) glView);//有改過

    /*x1=new GLLayer(this);
    glView.setRenderer(x1);*/ 
    setContentView(glView);

    addContentView(mPreview, new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));

}


@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)
{     super.onResume();
    if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
        myRender.light = !myRender.light;

    return super.onTouchEvent(event);
}




protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    if (counter>=2) {
        System.exit(0);
    }       
}}`
```

---

```
package de.offis.magic.core;

import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.ByteOrder;
import java.nio.FloatBuffer;
import java.nio.IntBuffer;

import javax.microedition.khronos.egl.EGLConfig;
import javax.microedition.khronos.opengles.GL10;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.PixelFormat;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.opengl.GLSurfaceView;
import android.opengl.GLU;
import android.opengl.GLSurfaceView.Renderer;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams;
import android.os.Bundle;
/**
 * This class uses OpenGL ES to render the camera's viewfinder image on the
 * screen. Unfortunately I don't know much about OpenGL (ES). The code is mostly
 * copied from some examples. The only interesting stuff happens in the main
 * loop (the run method) and the onPreviewFrame method.
 */
public class GLLayer extends GLSurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback,
        Camera.PreviewCallback, Renderer {

    int onDrawFrameCounter=1;
    int[] cameraTexture;
    byte[] glCameraFrame=new byte[1024*1024]; //size of a texture must be a power of 2
    FloatBuffer cubeBuff,cubeBuff2;
    FloatBuffer texBuff,texBuff2;
     public boolean light = true;

    public GLLayer(Context c) {
        super(c);

        this.setEGLConfigChooser(5, 6, 5, 8, 16, 0); // red, green, blue, alpha  depth
        this.setRenderer(this); //渲染
        this.getHolder().setFormat(PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT); //半透明
    }

    public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {
        onDrawFrameCounter++;


        gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
        gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL10.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT); //清除螢幕和深度緩存

        //bindCameraTexture(gl); //補camera捕捉到的變成紋理

        gl.glLoadIdentity();   //重置矩陣
        GLU.gluLookAt(gl, 0, 0, 4.2f, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0);//http://pyopengl.sourceforge.net/documentation/ref/glu/lookat.html
        gl.glTranslatef(-4,1,-3);
        gl.glRotatef(onDrawFrameCounter,1,10,0); //Rotate the camera image  角度 x y z
        gl.glTranslatef(-5,2,-3);
        gl.glRotatef((float)Math.tan(onDrawFrameCounter/20.0f)*10,0,1,0); //Rotate the camera image
        gl.glTranslatef(-1,0,0);
        gl.glRotatef((float)Math.sin(onDrawFrameCounter/20.0f)*100,1,0,0); //Rotate the camera image

        gl.glNormal3f(0,0,1);
        gl.glDrawArrays(GL10.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);          
        gl.glDrawArrays(GL10.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 4, 4);
        gl.glDrawArrays(GL10.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 8, 4);
        gl.glDrawArrays(GL10.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP,12, 4);
        gl.glDrawArrays(GL10.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP,16, 4);
        gl.glDrawArrays(GL10.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP,20, 4);





            gl.glRotatef((float)Math.sin(onDrawFrameCounter/20.0f)*100,1,0,0); //Rotate the camera image

        //bindCameraTexture(gl); //補camera捕捉到的變成紋理
        gl.glLoadIdentity(); 
        gl.glTranslatef(5,2,-6);
        gl.glRotatef(onDrawFrameCounter,0,1,0); //Rotate the camera image  角度 x y z
        gl.glNormal3f(0,0,1);
        gl.glDrawArrays(GL10.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);          
        gl.glDrawArrays(GL10.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 4, 4);
        gl.glDrawArrays(GL10.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 8, 4);
        gl.glDrawArrays(GL10.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP,12, 4);   
        gl.glDrawArrays(GL10.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP,16, 4);
        gl.glDrawArrays(GL10.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP,20, 4);   



        if (!light) 
        {
            gl.glTranslatef(-4,2,-6);

        }
        else
        {
            gl.glTranslatef(-4,2,-6);
        }





    }

    public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 gl, int width, int height) {
        gl.glViewport(0, 0, width, height);              // 設定圖形要顯示的區域


        float ratio = (float)2* width / height;
        gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_PROJECTION);          //設投影矩陣
        gl.glLoadIdentity();                          //重置
        gl.glFrustumf(-ratio, ratio, -1, 1, 1, 10);   //選擇模型觀察矩陣   

        gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_MODELVIEW);   
        gl.glLoadIdentity(); 
        GLU.gluLookAt(gl, 0, 0, 4.2f, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0);        
    }

    public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 gl, EGLConfig config) {
        gl.glHint(GL10.GL_PERSPECTIVE_CORRECTION_HINT, GL10.GL_FASTEST);

        gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 0);
        gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_CULL_FACE);
        gl.glShadeModel(GL10.GL_SMOOTH);
        gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_DEPTH_TEST);

        cubeBuff = makeFloatBuffer(camObjCoord);
        texBuff = makeFloatBuffer(camTexCoords);
        cubeBuff2 = makeFloatBuffer(camObjCoord);
        texBuff2 = makeFloatBuffer(camTexCoords);
        gl.glVertexPointer(3, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, cubeBuff);             //設頂點座標
        gl.glVertexPointer(3, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, cubeBuff2); 
        gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);                  //開紋理
        gl.glTexCoordPointer(2, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, texBuff);   
        gl.glTexCoordPointer(2, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, texBuff2);//將紋理連繫到物體 

        gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
    }   






    /**
     * Generates a texture from the black and white array filled by the onPreviewFrame
     * method.
     */
    void bindCameraTexture(GL10 gl) {
        synchronized(this) {
            if (cameraTexture==null)
                cameraTexture=new int[1];
            else
                gl.glDeleteTextures(1, cameraTexture, 0);

            gl.glGenTextures(1, cameraTexture, 0);  //建紋理
            int tex = cameraTexture[0];                  
            gl.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, tex);
            gl.glTexImage2D(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL10.GL_LUMINANCE, 256, 256, 0, GL10.GL_LUMINANCE, GL10.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, ByteBuffer.wrap(glCameraFrame));
            gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL10.GL_LINEAR);
        }
    }

    /**
     * This method is called if a new image from the camera arrived. The camera
     * delivers images in a yuv color format. It is converted to a black and white
     * image with a size of 256x256 pixels (only a fraction of the resulting image
     * is used). Afterwards Rendering the frame (in the main loop thread) is started by
     * setting the newFrameLock to true. 
     */
    public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] yuvs, Camera camera) {        
        int bwCounter=0;
        int yuvsCounter=0;
        for (int y=0;y<160;y++) {
            System.arraycopy(yuvs, yuvsCounter, glCameraFrame, bwCounter, 240);
            yuvsCounter=yuvsCounter+240;
            bwCounter=bwCounter+256;
        }
    }

    FloatBuffer makeFloatBuffer(float[] arr) {
        ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(arr.length*4);
        bb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
        FloatBuffer fb = bb.asFloatBuffer();
        fb.put(arr);
        fb.position(0);
        return fb;
    }




    final static float camObjCoord[] = new float[] {
                // FRONT
                 -2.0f, -1.5f,  2.0f,
              2.0f, -1.5f,  2.0f,
                 -2.0f,  1.5f,  2.0f,
                  2.0f,  1.5f,  2.0f,
                 // BACK
                 -2.0f, -1.5f, -2.0f,
                 -2.0f,  1.5f, -2.0f,
                  2.0f, -1.5f, -2.0f,
                  2.0f,  1.5f, -2.0f,
                 // LEFT
                 -2.0f, -1.5f,  2.0f,
                 -2.0f,  1.5f,  2.0f,
                 -2.0f, -1.5f, -2.0f,
                 -2.0f,  1.5f, -2.0f,
                 // RIGHT
                  2.0f, -1.5f, -2.0f,
                  2.0f,  1.5f, -2.0f,
                  2.0f, -1.5f,  2.0f,
                  2.0f,  1.5f,  2.0f,
                 // TOP
                 -2.0f,  1.5f,  2.0f,
                  2.0f,  1.5f,  2.0f,
                 -2.0f,  1.5f, -2.0f,
                  2.0f,  1.5f, -2.0f,
                 // BOTTOM
                 -2.0f, -1.5f,  2.0f,
                 -2.0f, -1.5f, -2.0f,
                  2.0f, -1.5f,  2.0f,
                  2.0f, -1.5f, -2.0f,
            };
            final static float camTexCoords[] = new float[] {
                // Camera preview
                 0.0f, 0.0f,
                 0.9375f, 0.0f,
                 0.0f, 0.625f,
                 0.9375f, 0.625f,

                // BACK
                 0.9375f, 0.0f,
                 0.9375f, 0.625f,
                 0.0f, 0.0f,
                 0.0f, 0.625f,
                // LEFT
                 0.9375f, 0.0f,
                 0.9375f, 0.625f,
                 0.0f, 0.0f,
                 0.0f, 0.625f,
                // RIGHT
                 0.9375f, 0.0f,
                 0.9375f, 0.625f,
                 0.0f, 0.0f,
                 0.0f, 0.625f,
                // TOP
                 0.0f, 0.0f,
                 0.9375f, 0.0f,
                 0.0f, 0.625f,
                 0.9375f, 0.625f,
                // BOTTOM
                 0.9375f, 0.0f,
                 0.9375f, 0.625f,
                 0.0f, 0.0f,
                 0.0f, 0.625f        
            };

}
```

**i want to touch the screen and then cube will change the position
i don't know where is wrong with my code   **

`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to implement the onTouchEvent(...) in your view class, rather than in the activity.
See the TouchRotateActivity example in the Android SDK

Answer (score 0):

```
glview.setonTouchListener(new View.onTouchListener(){

    public boolean onTouch(View v,MotionEvent event){

        int action = event.getAction();

        if(action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
        {
            //action to be performed
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```